# What does changing your character's 'heart' do?

Tags: crayon-chronicles

When creating your character in Crayon Chronicles, there's an option for choosing your 'heart'.  There's a bunch of different options to choose from.

The choices are as follows:

- Champion
- Dragon
- Glaiator
- Falcon
- Fox
- Hedgehog
- Lion
- Eagle
- Ogre
- Unicorn

I can't work out what the 'Heart' does though.  Is it just something to show up on your adventure record after you die to personalize your hero?  Or does it have some other effect on gameplay?

[image: Champion: Heart]

Comment: If you're going to upvote, you could at least leave a comment explaining why...